# FCM and AdMob with two different accounts?

Tags: android, firebase, admob, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is it possible to integrate FCM and AdMob in a single App from two different accounts?

Comment: no it's not possible

Comment: **NO** because AdMob is now a part of Firebase. refer this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/admob-firebase

Answer (score 0):

When you add FCM and Admob to your project, the first step is to configure the project and then to add google-services.json file in app folder, which have all the configurations that is needed to link your project. There can be only one google-services.json file in your project. So it's not possible to use two accounts for the same.